# Symfony console syntax for generating a Email field w/ the @Assert modifiers in Doctrine entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, console, entities, fieldtype

I have been able to generate entity email fields using:

```
    app/console doctrine:generate:entity  \
    --entity=VendorBundleNameBundle:tableName \
    --format=annotation \
    --fields= Email:email \
...
```

The result is as such:

```
 /**
 * @var email
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="Email", type="email")
 */
private $Email;
```

But what I would like to be able to generate is such:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @Assert\Email
 * @var string
 */
private $Email;
```

Comment: You can't generate constraints in console.